# SQL - select from variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

I am trying to find an alternative to setting the content of a variable as a big query in which i'm dynamically replacing values.
Is it possible to do something like this?

```
declare @serv nvarchar(max)
set @serv = '[linkedServName].[dataBaseName]'
select top 10 * from @serv.dbo.someTable
```

If yes, could you please show me the correct syntax?

Thank you for your time

Comment: you can't use this way, you need to use Dynamic SQL :)

Comment: You need `exec('your query')` for that

Comment: I see, thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to parameterize the server and database you select from, then you have to use dynamic sql. Try this:

```
declare @serv nvarchar(max)
declare @qry nvarchar(max)

set @serv = '[linkedServName].[dataBaseName]'
set @qry = 'select top 10 * from ' + @serv + '.dbo.someTable'

exec(@qry)
```

Comment: I was using it somehow simillar to this. So this would be the only way to go then? I was trying to avoid exactly this situation: in which i have an additional variable. Thank you for the answer, it is a really good and clear example

Comment: @CM2K I you want to parameterize the name, then dynamic sql is the only way I'm afraid.